# Ubuntu 20.04 fully installed on a USB drive has problems waking up from longer suspend times, how do I fix this?

Tags: 20.04, usb, suspend, live-usb

I have researched similar questions which asked about Ubuntu 20.04 freezing after waking up from suspends. This however, is different, that it entirely crashes and the screen goes into a black terminal-like screen which continuously outputs `systemd-journald failed to write/rotate` messages. I tried finding a log file of what I have seen in the `/var/log/` directory but couldn't find any. Please let me know where it could be logged and I shall attach the same here. For now, I have attached along an image below with terminal-like screen after crash from trying to wake from suspend:

[image: terminal-like screen after crash from trying to wake from suspend]

I have followed the guide written by CS Cameron here on AskUbuntu to create the USB drive with a full install of Ubuntu 20.04, [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step)

Everything seems to be fine but the waking up from long suspends. By long I mean, at least more than a couple of hours of suspending, the screen crashes to the terminal-like screen.  Shorter suspend times did not have any issues and the wake ups were without any issues. Please help! Also please point out any missing information that I could add to help improve the question. Thanks.

Comment: Is your Ubuntu 20.04 LTS fully updated & upgraded? Have you installed some additional application program(s)? Have you checked for file system errors (with `sudo e2fsck -cf /dev/sdx` ) and RAM errors (with memtest)?

Comment: Here in Sri Lanka the power goes out often, either from overheating computer or island wide power outage. From what I can recall, your sort of thing happens if the computer shuts down while it is writing to disk, (To the journal). Perhaps make sure all operations are complete before suspending. I am having a hard time duplicating the problem right now with a fresh USB and 20.04.2.